# Paperclip is not saving files in local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am using rails 4.1.6 and paperclip 4.2,

I have model like following:

```
class QcAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attachment,
                    :url => "/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
end
```

I had created only two columns for paperclip in database table named `attachment_file_name` and `attachment_content_type`

I got params like following:

`params=> { "temp_qc_id" => 1001, 
qc_attachment => { "temp_qc_id" => 1001, "attachment_file_name" => "temp_file.jpg", "attachment_content_type" => "image/jpg" } }`

When I create record using `QcAttachment.create(qc_attachment)`, the record has been saved and I got attachment object and values.

I get `attachment.path` = `/home/me/projects/temp_project/public/attachments/25/original/temp_file.jpg`

and 
`attachment.url` =
`/attachments/25/original/temp_file.jpg`

But, when I browse the `public` folder of `temp_project`directory, I didn't find out the `attachment` folder in it or any other folder and the file which I saved.

Logs are:

```
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `qc_attachments` (`created_at`, `temp_qc_id`, `attachment_content_type`, `attachment_file_name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-06-08 12:15:07', 10000001, 'image/png', 'temp_file.jpg', '2015-06-08 12:15:07')
   (18.1ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 38ms (Views: 1.2ms | ActiveRecord: 22.8ms)
```

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: Could be a problem with write permissions in the directory. Try giving permission, or manually creating a folder "attachments", in public folder.

Comment: You might find it under tmp folder or under assets

Comment: @Santhosh : I created the folder `attachments` unde public, and re-attach and save file and give full permissions to `public` folder, but it won't working.

Comment: @CaffeineCoder : not exists under `tmp` and `assets` folder

Comment: Can you post the logs after the image gets saved .

Comment: @CaffeineCoder : added logs at bottom of the question!!

Comment: @fidato You don't need to manually create attachments folder , paperclip does that . It makes folders id wise .

Comment: @CaffeineCoder : I did create it for only test purpose, and then removed it. I restarted rails server again and saved attachment, even Paperclip doesn't making the folder in my local machine. :(